# Dealing with a cached chunk that is still taking a long time to execute in R?

Tags: r, caching, google-bigquery, r-markdown, knitr

I currently have a 10million row table that I am uploading to R. I understand the uploading process to R make take some time and so as a consequence I decided to store my chunk as `chache = TRUE` and for good measure I did the following

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache = TRUE, warning = FALSE, 
                      message = FALSE, cache.lazy = FALSE)
```

When I re-run my RMarkdown document it is still taking >30minutes to execute the chunk that has the large data frame. Why are my results not being cached so that it does not need to take a long time to execute? I have made no changes to the query and the backend data has not updated as well.

Comment: Does that help https://yihui.org/en/2018/06/cache-invalidation/?

Comment: Potentially, only change I made is adding cache.comments = FALSE

Comment: if the cached objects are sufficiently gigantic it could a long time to load the cached information even though it is already in R binary format (which should have the fastest load time ...) ?

Answer (score 2):

In your question you have `chache = TRUE`, did you mean `cache = TRUE`?

You could also have the heavy processing done in it's own R script and call it inside your Rmarkdown with `source('rscript.R')`. Where caching is set in the .R file

as stated in [this link](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/cache.html) you can cache objects yourself with...

```
if (file.exists("results.rds")) {
  res <- readRDS("results.rds")
} else {
  res <- compute_it()  # a time-consuming function
  saveRDS(res, "results.rds")
}
```